# String in Python 3.4

Tags: python, string, python-3.4

I have this question of how to return true for strings. Can anyone help me on how to prompt user input in Python 3.4 and answer this question

Write a class/function to return True if 2 input strings are anagram to each other. string1 is an anagram of string2 if string2 can be obtained by rearranging the characters in string1.

```
Example:
string1 = 'smart'
string2 = 'marts'
result: True

string1 = 'secure'
string2 = 'rescue' 
result: True
```

Comment: Hint: Try to find an easy-to-achieve representation for both strings that is independent of the order of the characters in the string and compare those.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of ( warning untested code ):

```
def isAnagram(string1, string2):
    if sorted(list(string1)) == sorted(list(string2)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Admittedly there are more concise ways of doing this however this is particularly easy to understand in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def is_anagram(a, b):
    return True if sorted(a) == sorted(b) else False
```

Comment: Or just: `return sorted(a) == sorted(b)`